# Equal width flex columns when the container has fluid width

Tags: css, flexbox

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<div class="ungrouped-ordered-item">
    <div class="information-container">
        <div class="originating-order-id"> #00019405 </div>
        <div class="placed-by">  Placed by: 18175  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="indicator-container">
        <div class="indicator"> Unpaid </div>
        <div class="indicator" >Pending </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
.ungrouped-ordered-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.information-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.indicator-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.indicator-container .indicator {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #2e2240;
}
```

The design I am aiming for, is:

- to let the outermost flex containers (`.ungrouped-ordered-item`) children, grow as they need, and leave space between them, so that they are aligned to the left and right respectively of their containers
- to make the children of the inner flex container (`.indicator-container .indicator`) be equal-width, by taking up the width of the wider element (in this case, it being the element with the text "Pending")

My first goal is achieved, but it seems, that even if adding `flex: 1` to the `.indicator` containers, the browser will not correctly calculate the width of the two elements, and they will have uneven widths. I am presuming that this is because that their container, `.indicator-container`, has a fluid width. Am I right in this? How can I achieve my desired effect with all fluid width containers? (preferably without javascript).

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvh6fz2c/1/) also!

Comment: To be honest, i dont understand what you trying to achieve. Can you explain more your goal?

Comment: I want the two boxes, containing the "Pending" and "Unpaid" texts, to be equal-width, indiferent of their content (ie, the container with the shorter text, should take up the width of the container with the larger text).

Comment: What is the argument against a fixed width for the .indicatorbox? width: 50%;

Comment: @MaikLowrey in that case the two `.indicator` containers would always take up at least half of their container. I want the two boxes, to have the same width, that width being the width of the larger box (not larger then that) - I may have found a solution, using `grid`, will test, and post here as an answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

What is the argument against a width:50% for the `.indicator`box?

```css
.ungrouped-ordered-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.information-container {
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;  
}

.indicator-container {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;  
}
.indicator-container > * {
  border: 1px solid #2e2240;  
  padding: 0 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.indicator-container .indicator {  
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ungrouped-ordered-item">
    <div class="information-container">
        <div class="originating-order-id"> #00019405 </div>
        <div class="placed-by">  Placed by: 18175  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="indicator-container">
        <div class="indicator"> Unpaid </div>
        <div class="indicator" >Pending long long</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see how you mean `50%` now. For my specific example, it indeed does the trick, but if later on I intend to add another `indicator`, I need to change the `css` too, while with my solution, it will work automatically (I think, haven't tried it out, but logically it should)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `.indicator-container` class from `flex` to `grid` and using automatic columns solves my problem. Although, it doesn't have as much coverage as `flex`, for my needs, this works:

```
.indicator-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
   grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvh6fz2c/2/) also.

Comment: Okay. That do the job too. I think it does the same as width: 50% too. here is the example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71636237/14807111